# Get type of null array

Tags: c#, .net, types

I'm working on some serialization routines, and I need a way to get the type of an input array.

Let's say I have the following object:

```
class myclass {
    public int foo;
    public byte[] bar;
}
```

Now I can get the type of `myclass.foo` by using `GetType()`. And if I say that "`myclass.bar = new byte[0]`", I can infer that `bar` is an array of bytes by using `GetElementType()`, `HasElementType`, and `IsArray`.

However if I never set `bar` and just leave it as `null`, I can't find a way to get the type info off the object. If I do `myclass.foo.GetType()` all I get is a null value.

Is there anyway to infer the type of "bar" in this case?

Comment: Here's a related post on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120839/net-c-reflection-list-the-fields-of-a-field-that-itself-has-fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nonexistent object doesn't have a type. It doesn't make sense to get the type of a `null` reference. What you are looking for is actually the type of the field. You can get that by reflecting over the type *declaring* the field (in this case, `myclass`).

Answer (score 4):

I think reflection should work -

```
typeof(myclass).GetField("bar").FieldType
```

Comment: I don't get a NullReferenceException with that code, nor should you (unless the field doesn't exist, in which case Type.GetField(string) will return null, but as long as your names are correct you shouldn't get a NullReferenceException).

Comment: dsolimano's method should work, MSDN's reference has something similar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0cs7xez.aspx