# How can I build an Expression with dynamic comparison operators for an unknown number of filters?

Tags: c#, expression, lazy-loading, .net-core-3.1

I'm new to expression building, so bear with me a little bit.

I'm building off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3782996/1630629), using [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) for building a predicate with an unknown number of filters. Say I have these classes:

```
public FilterTerm
{
    public string ComparisonOperatorA { get; set; }
    public decimal ValueA { get; set; }
    public string ComparisonOperatorB { get; set; }
    public decimal ValueB { get; set; }
    public string ComparisonOperatorC { get; set; }
    public decimal ValueC { get; set; }
}

public Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal SkillLevelA { get; set; }
    public decimal SkillLevelB { get; set; }
    public decimal SkillLevelC { get; set; }
}
```

where `FilterTerm.ComparisonOperator[A|B|C]` can be any of `>, >=, <, <=, ==`, which a user submits N `FilterTerm`s to filter results from the db (via EF context) `Item`s. My main query is set up this way:

```
[...]

List<FilterTerm> filterTerms = GetFilterTerms();

var itemsQuery = context.GetAll<Item>(); // reutrns IQueryable<Item>
itemsQuery = itemsQuery.ApplyFilters(filterTerms);

var items = await itemsQuery.ToListAsync();

[...]
```

I'm building the base predicate like this, with missing knowledge (I'm using assigned variables in the loop so values aren't evaluated at execution time):

```
private IQueryable<Item> ApplyFilters(IQueryable<Item> query, FilterTerms filterTerms)
{ 
    Expression<Func<Item, bool>> superPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Item>()
    foreach (var filterTerm in filterTerms)
    {
        Expression<Func<Item, bool>> subPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Item>();

        subPredicate = subPredicate.And<Item>(GetDynamicPredicate(i => i.SkillLevelA, filterTerm.ValueA, filterTerm.ComparisonOperatorA));
        subPredicate = subPredicate.And<Item>(GetDynamicPredicate(i => i.SkillLevelB, filterTerm.ValueB, filterTerm.ComparisonOperatorB));
        subPredicate = subPredicate.And<Item>(GetDynamicPredicate(i => i.SkillLevelC, filterTerm.ValueC, filterTerm.ComparisonOperatorC));

        superPredicate = superPredicate.Or(subPredicate);
    }
    
    return query.Where(superPredicate);
}

private Expression<Func<Item, bool>> GetDynamicPredicate(XXXX xxxx, decimal value, string comparisonOperator)
{
    Expression<Func<Item, bool>> predicate;

    switch (comparisonOperator)
    {
        case "<":
            predicate = Expression.LessThan(xxxx, value);
            break;
        [...]
    }

    return predicate;
}
```

where I don't know what to have for `XXXX xxxx`, which I prefer to have as a term selector like `i => i.[Property]` (is it possible to do this in a way that maintains Query building before sending it to the DB for execution?), and I know that the `Expression.LessThan` requires `Expression left, Expression right` for the signature, but I'm stuck with how to complete this.

I've seen questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738919/set-comparison-operator-dynamically-using-lambda-expression), but I just I can't seem to figure out how to apply the answers to my use case. Can anyone help provide the missing knowledge? It's been a few hours of trial-and-error, and I may just need something spoon-fed to me to connect the dots... I think I'm missing some steps with `BinaryExpression` and `Lambda` building, but I just can't piece it together.

Comment: IMHO create a dictionary of operator strings to `ExpressionType` values so you can call `Expression.MakeBinary` instead of a switch for each individual comparison type. (Note that `.MakeBinary` already has that switch statement https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/537a547f74287a625055b0a57dc29ff548edb176/src/libraries/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/BinaryExpression.cs#L898)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I was going to be creating an Enum for operators to strongly type and ensure input, but this is waaaay better! I've been tasked with converting a bunch of SQL Server SPs into EF+LINQtoSQL, so as I've been going I've been building a library of helpful/reusable methods, and my god is that good to know. Cheers, thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can sometimes get a bit daunting when working with expression trees, but your use-case is not too hard.  The key bit you need is how to fill in the arguments to `LessThan`.  The short version is that it should look like this:

```
predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(
    Expression.LessThan(property.Body, Expression.Constant(value)), property.Parameters[0]);
```

That requires you to change your parameter to match the incoming lambda which specifies a property, so the complete solution is for your method to look like:

```
private Expression<Func<Item, bool>> GetDynamicPredicate<TValue>(
    Expression<Func<Item, TValue>> property, decimal value, string comparisonOperator)
{
    Expression<Func<Item, bool>> predicate = null;

    switch (comparisonOperator)
    {
        case "<":
            predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(
                Expression.LessThan(property.Body, Expression.Constant(value)),
                property.Parameters[0]);
            break;
    }

    return predicate;
}
```

Now for a breakdown of the changes we made.

First we changed the `GetDynamicPredicate` method so that the type of the first parameter is `Expression<Func<Item, TValue>>`, since a lambda requires an input and output type.  That required adding the generic parameter `TValue` to your method.

Next we know that the incoming lambda is of the form `x => x.Property`.  What we actually want is `x => x.Property < value`.  Fortunately that's a really simple transformation.  We know that the body is `x.Property` so we simply have to use that when calling `LessThan`, as that is what we're comparing against.

The value is easy: `Expression.Constant` will work just fine for most values.

Finally, we need the `predicate` variable to contain a lambda expression, so we need to call `Expression.Lambda`, grabbing the existing parameter from the incoming lambda for convenience.

Comment: Since property is `TValue`, `decimal value` should probably be the same. Otherwise you'd need to insert a conversion for the comparison to work.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much! The breakdown explanation is amazing, it definitely helps me piece together what I was missing. Cheers, and thanks for the help!

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, I agree, and there are several other ways I would generalize this code myself, but in terms of answering the OP's question, I was trying to minimize changes to the code so that the answer would be as clear as possible. That said, it's good advice.

Comment: @KirkWoll Indeed it is good advice, and I do appreciate your adapting to my circumstance for clarity. My current use-case is a specific `decimal` implementation, but my ultimate intent is to have this generalized, and so using `Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> property, TValue value` in the signature will be what I end up doing. :)

Comment: Hey @KirkWoll sorry to bug you with this again, but it turns out I need to apply this on a collection of `Item`s on an object `Course`, but when I try to do `query = query.Include(c => c.Items.Where(superPredicate.Compile()))` and I'm getting an error I don't understand the cause of. Can you check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71876163/how-can-i-use-a-built-expression-in-an-include-where-to-apply-an-include-filt?

Comment: @Daevin sure, I'll take a look at it.