# How can I use a built Expression in an Include .Where() to apply an Include Filter when it expects Expression but only allows Func?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression, func, .net-core-3.1

I'm getting some errors trying to build expression trees on nested collections. I have classes:

```
// not DB entity
public FilterTerm
{
    public string ComparisonOperatorA { get; set; }
    public decimal? ValueA { get; set; }
    public string ComparisonOperatorB { get; set; }
    public decimal? ValueB { get; set; }
    public string ComparisonOperatorC { get; set; }
    public decimal? ValueC { get; set; }
}

// not DB entity
public CourseFilter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<FilterTerm> FilterTerms { get; set; }
}

// DB entity
public Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal? SkillLevelA { get; set; }
    public decimal? SkillLevelB { get; set; }
    public decimal? SkillLevelC { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Course")]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}

// DB entity
public Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm trying to query my db (via EF context) to collect all of the `Course`s that contain items based on a `CourseFilter` submitted by a user:

```
[...]

CourseFilter searchParameters = GetSearchParameters();

var coursesQuery = context.GetAll<Course>(); // reutrns IQueryable<Course>
coursesQuery = coursesQuery.ApplyFilters(searchParameters);

var courses = await coursesQuery.ToListAsync();

[...]

    private IQueryable<Course> ApplyFilters(IQueryable<Course> query, CourseFilter searchParameters)
{ 
    query = query.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(searchParameters.Name));

    query = query.Where(c => c.Type == searchParameters.Type);

    Expression<Func<Item, bool>> superPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Item>()
    foreach (var filterTerm in searchParameters.FilterTerms)
    {
        Expression<Func<Item, bool>> subPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Item>();

        subPredicate = subPredicate.And<Item>(GetDynamicPredicate(i => i.SkillLevelA, filterTerm.ValueA, filterTerm.ComparisonOperatorA));
        subPredicate = subPredicate.And<Item>(GetDynamicPredicate(i => i.SkillLevelB, filterTerm.ValueB, filterTerm.ComparisonOperatorB));
        subPredicate = subPredicate.And<Item>(GetDynamicPredicate(i => i.SkillLevelC, filterTerm.ValueC, filterTerm.ComparisonOperatorC));

        superPredicate = superPredicate.Or(subPredicate);
    }
    
    query = query.Include(c => c.Items.Where(superPredicate.Compile()))
                .Where(c => c.Items.Count > 0);

    return query;
}

private Expression<Func<Item, bool>> GetDynamicPredicate<TValue>(
    Expression<Func<Item, decimal?>> property, decimal? value, string comparisonOperator)
{
    Expression<Func<Item, bool>> predicate = null;

    switch (comparisonOperator)
    {
        case "<":
            predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(
                Expression.LessThan(property.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(decimal?))),
                property.Parameters[0]);
            break;
        [...]
    }

    return predicate;
}
```

My problem here is that the Include Filter for the query requires the `superPredicate.Compile()` or, pre-compile/compile time, Visual Studio provides the error:

```
`Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<DTO.Item, bool>>' to 'System.Func<DTO.Item, bool>'`
```

However, when using the `superPredicate.Compile()` during runtime I get the error:

```
Expression of type 'System.Func`2[DTO.Item,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[DTO.Item,System.Boolean]]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DTO.Item] Where[DTO.Item](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DTO.Item], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[DTO.Item,System.Boolean]])' (Parameter 'arg1')
```

Same issues if I try to filter this way:

```
query = query
    .Include(d => d.Items)
    .Where(d => d.Items.Where(superPredicate.Compile()).Count() > 0);
```

Is it possible to resolve this error and be able to use the Include Filter? If not, is there a way I can do what I want to do in a single query?

If it helps, this is to convert a SQL Server SP to EF, where the SP is in essence:

```
@sql = 'SELECT *
            FROM dbo.Course c
            INNER JOIN dbo.Item i
                on i.CourseId = c.Id
            WHERE (c.Name LIKE @CourseName)
                AND (c.Type = @CourseType)'
    [below is added using a cursor over N filters and covers <,<=,>,>=,=
     (represented as integers) for SkillLevelA,B,C on Item, and emulated 
     in the ApplyFilters and GetDynamicQuery methods]
        @sql = @sql + 'AND ((' + @CO_A + ' = 1 AND (' + @ValueA' < i.SkillLevelA)) OR ([etc]))'
```

Comment: AFAIK without 3rd party libraries you need to build whole expression for `Where`/`Include`.

Comment: Can you try just replacing `query.Include(c => c.Items.Where(superPredicate.Compile()))` with `query.Include(c => c.Items.AsQueryable().Where(superPredicate))`.  I'm pretty sure that will work.

Comment: @KirkWoll that yields `Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.`, but when I use the Where outside of the Include as `query.Include(c => c.Items).Where(c => c.Items.AsQueryable().Where(superPredicate).Count() > 0)` it works! At least, I think it does, there are no errors and the query returns an empty list lol so my test filters need some testing haha. Thanks for all your help, you're a life-saver. If you post an answer with your `AsQueryable` and the `Where` outside of the `Include`, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Daevin hmm, you should make sure that the `Items` on the returned courses are respecting your filter, as I suspect it is not.  That said, I did try this (in LinqPad with one of my own databases) and it definitely works for me.  I assume you're on the latest version of EF?  Or perhaps not?

Comment: Also, you should make sure that the `Include/Where` thing you're trying actually works with just normal syntax as a test.  Because this "filtered include" feature was added in EF5, so possibly that's the issue.  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include)

Comment: @KirkWoll I'll take a look, but I jump to assume it's my sample filter because I haphazardly put random values together to ensure that the query would build and execute without throwing errors. The project uses EF Core 3.1.15 (which I wasn't aware of prior, or I would have tagged properly), so not the latest, no.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. I wasn't aware the project was using an older version of EF Core (which is not what was discussed for the project). I'm going to investigate options.

Comment: @Daevin one thing that might work for you is making your query on items the root of your query and including the `Course` property instead (i.e. the other way around).  That would avoid your having to take advantage of that unsupported feature in your version of EF.  Just a thought.  Then again, if course has no items, your query won't end up with a course.

Comment: @KirkWoll so, a month later and several other issues coming up, we are going to be upgrading the project to EF6. You were right about that being the main cause, and inverting the query was usable, but once the upgrade has been completed I will be using the `.Include(c => c.Items.Where([...]))` solution. If you post that as an answer I will mark it accepted. Cheers, thanks for all your help!

Comment: Thanks for circling back, and I'm glad you were able to make the upgrade to EF6 happen, as it's nice to be able to stay on the latest versions.  I'll post an answer momentarily so you can close the loop on this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discovered in the comments, the main problem is that the feature you are trying to use ("filtered include") is one that was [introduced in EF5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include), and you are/were evidently on an earlier version.

This feature is what allows you to filter the included relationships by using a `.Where` clause.  However, even after upgrading, you still need to make sure you are using expression trees all the way through to make EF happy.

So this line here where you are calling `Compile()` is going in the wrong direction for you.

```
query = query
    .Include(c => c.Items.Where(superPredicate.Compile()))
    .Where(c => c.Items.Count > 0);
```

Because `Items` is seen at compile time as an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of an `IQueryable<T>`, you naturally tried to make your `superPredicate` work by coercing it into a predicate that uses a normal non-expression-tree lambda (`Compile` converts the expression into a normal lambda).  However, EF won't know what to do with the lambda -- it needs the expression tree to map it to SQL.

So you simply have to go the other way and  make `c.Items` a queryable instead of an enumerable by calling `.AsQueryable` instead:

```
query.Include(c => c.Items.AsQueryable().Where(superPredicate))
```

This should now function properly and populate your `Items` property with the filtered list of items as defined by your `superPredicate`.

Comment: Amazingly thorough answer.